# Scroll to next <article>

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a JavaScript function that will scroll to the next article whenever the down arrow key is pressed.  All my HTML elements are dynamic, and are all just article tags with no ID.  The script I have so far can recognize the down key being pressed, but from this point, I have no idea how to make a function that will scroll down to the next article tag without naming the articles or something like that.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 40) {
        // function  to scroll down
    }});
```

I think I will need to create a variable that is just any article element within my HTML page.  Is that even possible?  If so, how would I do that, and make the function scroll down to the next article?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to have only one article / page? Or is it ok to use something like <a href="#NextArticle"> (I mean from the behavioral point of view) having all articles on the same page?

Comment: There is only one page with infinite scrolling.  My idea is to simply scroll down to the next <article> with a JavaScript function.  So I think I'd say no to an href="#nextArticle"

Comment: See this: http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `window.scrollTo` function. All you need is to identify Y offset of next article. You can do it by calculating `offsetTop` of that node (plus all its `offsetParent` nodes).

Another solution: use `element.scrollIntoView()` or `element.scorllIntoViewIfNeeded()`. It's cross-browser too, but I would prefer first solution because it allows you to you can control animation and it will work even in oldest browsers.

Comment: This is the right idea - If you have no easy way of keeping track of articles, I suggest just toggling the class 'active' on the most prominent article in the viewport or something similar. By pressing up or down, you can find the next or previous article using $('article.active').next() or $('article.active').prev() and window.scrollTo() to the offsetTop of the found element.

Comment: This makes some sense to me, and I tried doing this.  But whenever I press the down arrow now, chrome's console will tell me that "article" is not defined.

Comment: Cole Z., as Steve Adams said, main problem here is not scroll, but getting right element (article). You can find all articles on the page (`document.querySelectorAll('.article-class-name')`), and then loop them comparing each element's offsetTop with current `window.scrollY`.

Rich Hitchcock, I prefer scrollTo, because it's rare case when you only need to jump somewhere, more often you want to jump in several steps to animate your scroll movement. So that you can find difference between your scrollY and desired position and call scrollTo in setInterval.